# Frag shader not compiled for random symbols at the end of the source on Android

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, shader

Files loading func:

```
std::string path = std::string(fileLink.path)
                   + std::string(fileLink.name)
                   + std::string(".")
                   + std::string(fileLink.type);

AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(AndroidWrapper::Get()->GetAssetMgr(), path.c_str(), AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

long size = AAsset_getLength(asset);
char* data = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * size + 1);

AAsset_read(asset, data, size);
AAsset_close(asset);

DATA* fileData = new DATA;
fileData->data = data;
fileData->size = size;

return fileData;
```

Sometimes shader loads fine, but mostly its loading with random symbols at the end, for example

```
I/ExampleApp: Shader code: varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

                           void main()
                           {
                               gl_FragColor = colorVarying;
                           }
                           de
```

And shader loading func calling

```
if (!CompileShader(&fragShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragShaderData->data))
{
    LOGE("Failed to compile frgment shader", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Text files are not the same as NUL byte terminated strings. If you allocate for *exactly* the file size and read exactly the file length, there will be no (proper) terminating NUL byte at the end of the buffer. That in itself is not a problem, since you can pass the shader source length explicitly to `glSourceString`. However if you do not do that, `glSourceString` expects NUL by terminate source strings.

The solution to your problem: Either pass the shader source size explicitly or append a NUL byte at the end.